# How can I make schemaspy work with SQL Server 2016 (v13)?

Tags: sql-server, schemaspy

last I used schemaspy was with SQL Server 2005 or 2008 in 2017. I tried it against a SQL Server 2016 (v13) instance and I can't find a jar file for the database connection that will work.

Comment: I'm *assuming* by SQL Server 13 you mean SQL Server **2016** (v13) - right?

Comment: yes sql server 2016

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it to connect using the following settings in schemaspygui

```
   DB Type:  mssql05
   DB Host: ipaddressOfDB
   DB Port:  1433
   DB Driver: mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre8.jar
   SchemaSpy Version:  schemaspy-6.1.0.jar
```